# Halt a Shell Pipe Once Any Chain is Finished

Tags: shell, pipe

Is it possible on such a pipe line

```
tee stdin.log | subject-command | tee stdout.log
```

to halt an execution once `subject-command` is finished.

Instead as I experience it the first `tee` proceeds while its income stream goes on.

Comment: This isn't a general shell-pipe problem, it's specifically a `tee` problem. _In general_, UNIX programs are expected to treat it as an error and exit as soon as they attempt to write to stdout and fail; and pipe-oriented programs are also expected to exit when their stdin is closed and they've finished doing whatever processing that stdin demands. However, `tee` is specified to be more resilient, keeping running as long as at least one file output is still valid; the current spec isn't explicit except by reference about how to handle stdout closing

Comment: (and older versions of the spec were less explicit about error handling than the current one is).

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of `tee` varies by operating system. When given multiple explicit file outputs it keeps going until all of them have failed; whether it should exit immediately when stdout failed is somewhat open to interpretation in the standard defining its behavior. (I'd argue that failing to exit in this case is a bug and should be reported to your OS vendor, but that doesn't help you when you have a problem *now*).

Assuming bash 4.1 or newer, and that you're processing line-oriented textual content that doesn't contain any NULs:

```
mytee() {
  local arg new_fd
  local -a fds=( )

  # open our output files
  for arg in "$@"; do
    exec {new_fd}>"$arg"
    fds+=( "$new_fd" )
  done

  # loop over input until first failure
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    for fd in "${fds[@]}"; do
      printf '%s\n' "$line" >&"$fd" || break
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$line" || break
  done

  # close our output files
  for fd in "${fds[@]}"; do
    exec {fd}>&-
  done
}
```

...the problem described in this question will no longer occur with:

```
mytee stdin.log | subject-command | tee stdout.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the issues specific to `tee`, we can work around this with process substitutions (another ksh/zsh/bash feature not available in sh).

This too requires a relatively recent bash release and isn't compatible with `sh` (as process substitutions didn't set `$!` until release 4.3 or so).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- only bash, not sh

exec {stdin_log_tee_fd}< <(tee stdin.log); stdin_log_tee_pid=$!
subject-command <&$stdin_log_tee_fd | tee stdout.log
kill "$stdin_log_tee_pid"
```